# Setting a View when a user edits an Item via an InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath, view

I've created an InfoPath form with four views which represents four different sections of the form. When a user completes one View and submits a Nintex Approval is kicked off. When the section is approved they get the next section/view to complete. The user should be able to see the first section, I've made it Read-Only and be able to fill in the section.

I've been able to create a link to the view which incorporates the first section/view and the second section/view however when I click on the link and Edit Item it goes to the Default View and I need it go to the View I've created which has the Read-Only fields on it.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? [image: View Image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use InfoPath view name in link with DefaultView query string parameter.

```
http://www.myspsite.com/sites/mylist/item/editifs.aspx?ID=123&DefaultView=MyViewName
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm able to do that too - http://myspsitecom//Tools/Lists/Infrastructure%20Specification%20v2/DispForm.aspx?ID=5&InfrastructureSoftwareSpecREADONLY. 

What I need is that View to be the one that a user edits when they click on Edit Item

Comment: I don't know if its is possible. But you can do this using custom buttons. Hide ribbon on form, but a button on page with "Edit" text on it and set a button click rule to change view.